# Sonata Admin datetime picker returns wrong time

Tags: symfony, datetimepicker, sonata-admin

I'm new in Symfony, so excuse my ignorance.
I try to edit date and time of some event using Sonata Admin and 'sonata_type_datetime_picker' field type.
But sonata_type_datetime_picker return wrong time. It gives time for an hour less.

[Here's a filled form field screenshot (time is 10:00):](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Th0xx.png)

[Here's dump of form field value (time is 09:00):](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGZjp.png)

Here's form field options:

```
    ->add('datebegin', 'sonata_type_datetime_picker', array(
        'format'            => 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm',
        'label'             => 'Event begins at...',
        'dp_use_current'    => false,
        'model_timezone'    => 'Europe/Moscow'
    ))
```

I'd like to note that this error exists only on the server. On my local machine everything is ok.
What could it be?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 4):

I've got this problem too. I think that you need to upgrade the software on your server (packet: tzdata etc).

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moscow_Time

If this doesn't help you, you can use this hack:

```
'view_timezone' => 'Europe/Minsk'
```

See:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC%2B03:00
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minsk (UTC+3)

For example:

```
->add('endTimestamp', 'sonata_type_datetime_picker', array(
        'widget' => 'single_text',
        'label' => 'sip_event_end_timestamp',
        'dp_side_by_side'       => true,
        'dp_use_seconds'        => false,
        'model_timezone'        => 'Europe/Moscow',
        'view_timezone'         => 'Europe/Minsk',
        'format' => 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm'
    )
)
```